# Unable to read JVM arguments in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am running a spring boot jar in command prompt passing jvm arguments like

```
java -jar myjarname.jar -Denvironment=dev
```

or

```
java -jar myjarname.jar --environment=dev
```

and trying to read the value `environment` in my application using System.getProperty("environment"). But it is giving me null value. Please help!!

Comment: `--environment=dev` will not show up as system property. The form using `-Denvironment=dev` is correct. But why are you actually trying to read it out using `System.getProperty("environment")`? It is way easier to use `@Value`-injection.

Comment: You are right.. But I have a dependency jar where they are reading using System.getproperty() method.  -Denvironment way is working if I use mvn spring-boot:run command. I need to run using java command where If i pass this argument, it is not working..

Comment: Please check https://github.com/deichten/spring-boot-env-vars I setup a super simple demo project and it works for me. Important: try launching the app using `java -Denvironment=dev -jar myjarname.jar`. The reason for that is that all the stuff after the jar is passed as params to the Spring application.

Comment: Thank you @hrrgttnchml.. you are correct..I found it from another spring link too..https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to pass the parameters you want to make accessible to your application before specifying the app.jar. So

```
java -jar application.jar -Denvironment=dev
```

will not work whereas

```
java -Denvironment=dev -jar application.jar
```

will work.